# Trying to implement a shell with execp, dup2 and pipe, hangs or "bad file descriptor"

Tags: c++, shell, pipe, dup2

I'm trying to implement a shell with piping in c++. I've got commands working, but once pipes get involved, things stop working. I'll show you what I mean. Here's the code:

```
    int inPipe[2];
    int outPipe[2];
    pipe(inPipe);
    pipe(outPipe);

    int std_in = dup(0);
    int std_out = dup(1);
    std::for_each(cmds.begin(), cmds.end(), [&](Command command){
        //printf("Executing [%s] \n", command.args[0].c_str());
        auto pid = fork();
        if(pid==-1) {
            std::cerr << "Could not fork\n";
            return;
        }
        if (pid==0) {
            //std::cout << "Child\n";

            if(command.inFile == "none") {
                printf("In, none.\n");
                dup2(std_in, 0);
                close(std_in);
            }
            else if(command.inFile == "pipe") {
                printf("In, pipe.\n");
                dup2(inPipe[0], 0);
                close(inPipe[0]);
            }

            if(command.outFile == "none") {
                printf("Out, none.\n");
                dup2(std_out, 1);
                close(std_out);
            }
            else if(command.outFile == "pipe") {
                printf("out, pipe.\n");
                dup2(outPipe[1], 1);
                close(outPipe[1]);
            }

            const char* name = command.args[0].c_str();
            char** args = new char*[command.args.size()];
            for(int i=0; i<command.args.size(); i++) {
                args[i] = new char[command.args[i].size()];
                strcpy(args[i], command.args[i].c_str());
            }

            execvp(name, args);
            exit(errno);
        }
        else {
            //std::cout << "Parent\n";
            int status;
            auto before = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

            dup2(outPipe[0], inPipe[0]);
            dup2(outPipe[1], inPipe[1]);
            close(outPipe[0]);
            close(outPipe[1]);
            pipe(outPipe);

            waitpid(pid, &status, 0);


            auto after = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            std::chrono::duration<double> ptime = after-before;
            elapsed_time = elapsed_time + ptime.count();
        }
    });
```

When I run single pipe commands, like a simple "ls", it works fine. However, if I use ls | sort, it gives this error message:

```
ls: cannot access : No such file or directory
```

and then hangs until I ^c out of there. I think the hang comes from me mishandling the pipes somehow (not closing them), but I don't know where or how many times to put that in. I think the "cannot access" comes from me losing std_in before being able to call ls somehow. I'm new to almost all of these functions (dup2, fork, execp, pipe, etc) so I feel like my guess and check is more like 6-round russian roulette.

Anyway, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check Variables Name and Args,
one of those values might be NULL